# How to navigate to particular objectivec page when tap on notification that too when app is not running state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, appdelegate

My app is in not running state I tap on notification its open home page but I want to open particular page, but its work for when app is in foreground and in background, but I wrote this code in one method of app delegate alert view is displaying for all state.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
         {

          NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
           NSDictionary *dict = userInfo[kAps];
           NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:kAlert]];
           UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
           MyOrderDetailVC *view =  [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMainStoryboard bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyOrderDetailVC"];

           NSString *orderstatus = userInfo[kgcmnotificationorderstatus];
           NSString *ordertype = userInfo[kgcmnotificationordertype];
           view.isFromSideMenu = YES;
           view.isfromViewOrders = YES;
           view.status =  orderstatus;  //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictOrderDetails valueForKey:korderstatus]];
           view.isProduct =ordertype;
           view.strOrderStatus = orderstatus;
           view.strProgramId = @"-1";
           if([ordertype isEqualToString: @"0"])
           {
           view.isBookedOrders = NO;
           }
           if([ordertype isEqualToString: @"1"])
           {
             view.isBookedOrders =YES;
           }
           if([orderstatus isEqualToString:@"0"])
           {
             view.strOrderStatus = kPending;
           }
           else if([orderstatus isEqualToString:@"1"])
           {
             view.strOrderStatus = kConfirmed;
           }
           else if ([orderstatus isEqualToString:@"2"])
           {
             view.strOrderStatus = kCompleted;
           }
           [navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];

     [[Shared sharedInstance] showAlertViewInViewController:kAppName message:str buttonTitles:@[OK] viewC:self.window.rootViewController handler:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your App is not running and you want to detect your `Notification` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method like below

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{    
  UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];    
  if (localNotif) {
     // Notification detect here
     // Put your code here so it will be call when your App will not running state and tapped on Notification.
  }    
}
```

Comment: But it going to "- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler" this method because its displaying alert view which is called in side this method, but is not navigating to other page which is writing in this method only.

Comment: You can get Application state by if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
         //opened from a push notification when the app was on background
    }

Answer (score 0):

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions check notification is or note

```
NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (notification)
{
    NSLog(@"app recieved notification %@",notification);
  // open your particular controller


}else{
    NSLog(@"app did not recieve  notification");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but also when i tap on notification its going to home page and displaying alert view but not navigating to the particular page.

Comment: You can open partilcaur view controller as this   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    Yourcontroller *myVC = (Yourcontroller *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourcontrollerId”]; [self.navigationController pushViewController: myVC animated:YES];